# MongoDB aggregation query performance with in-memory storage engine

Tags: mongodb

We have a collection with 1 million records with avg object size 1.2 KB. The storage engine we are using is in-memory and the machine has 8GB RAM and 8 cores CPU. An aggregation query on the whole DB takes around 7 secs. Isn't it too large?. Given that all of the data is in memory. The aggregation query is given below.

Please guide us through the things that we are lacking and help us in improving the query response time. Since the whole DB is needs to be queried indexing is not going to help. What are the other ways in which the performance can be improved?.

Thanks in advance.

```
[  
   {  
      "$addFields":{  
         "year":{  
            "$year":"$created_at"
         },
         "week":{  
            "$week":"$created_at"
         },
         "month":{  
            "$month":"$created_at"
         },
         "day":{  
            "$dayOfYear":"$created_at"
         },
         "budget":[  
            {  
               "$substr":[  
                  "$min_budget",
                  0,
                  -1
               ]
            },
            " - ",
            {  
               "$substr":[  
                  "$max_budget",
                  0,
                  -1
               ]
            }
         ],
         "age_group":{  
            "$concat":[  
               {  
                  "$substr":[  
                     "$extra_details.min_age",
                     0,
                     -1
                  ]
               },
               " - ",
               {  
                  "$substr":[  
                     "$extra_details.max_age",
                     0,
                     -1
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      "$group":{  
         "visits_so_far":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$ne":[  
                        {  
                           "$type":"$status_timestamps.visit_done_timestamp"
                        },
                        "missing"
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "junk":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$ne":[  
                        {  
                           "$type":"$status_timestamps.junk_timestamp"
                        },
                        "missing"
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "interested_so_far":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$ne":[  
                        {  
                           "$type":"$status_timestamps.interested_timestamp"
                        },
                        "missing"
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "in_visit_done":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$eq":[  
                        "$current_status.id",
                        9
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "in_claimed":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$eq":[  
                        "$current_status.id",
                        6
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "ignored":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$or":[  
                        {  
                           "$and":[  
                              {  
                                 "$and":[  
                                    {  
                                       "$lte":[  
                                          "$status_updated_at",
                                          "2019-07-17T13:53:19.376754Z"
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {  
                                       "$and":[  
                                          {  
                                             "$gte":[  
                                                "$current_status.id",
                                                6
                                             ]
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "$lte":[  
                                                "$current_status.id",
                                                10
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              },
                              {  
                                 "$eq":[  
                                    {  
                                       "$type":"$event_max_timestamp"
                                    },
                                    "missing"
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {  
                           "$and":[  
                              {  
                                 "$and":[  
                                    {  
                                       "$lte":[  
                                          "$status_updated_at",
                                          "2019-07-17T13:53:19.395957Z"
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {  
                                       "$lte":[  
                                          "$event_max_timestamp",
                                          "2019-07-17T13:53:19.396016Z"
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {  
                                       "$and":[  
                                          {  
                                             "$gte":[  
                                                "$current_status.id",
                                                6
                                             ]
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "$lte":[  
                                                "$current_status.id",
                                                10
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              },
                              {  
                                 "$ne":[  
                                    {  
                                       "$type":"$event_max_timestamp"
                                    },
                                    "missing"
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "failed":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$ne":[  
                        {  
                           "$type":"$status_timestamps.failed_timestamp"
                        },
                        "missing"
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "channel_source_id_name":{  
            "$first":"$current_inquiry.channel_source"
         },
         "bookings":{  
            "$sum":{  
               "$cond":[  
                  {  
                     "$eq":[  
                        "$current_status.id",
                        11
                     ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
               ]
            }
         },
         "_id":{  
            "channel_sub_source_id":"$current_inquiry.channel_sub_source_id",
            "channel_source_id":"$current_inquiry.channel_source_id",
            "channel_id":"$current_inquiry.channel_id"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

The sample input document is as follows.

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5d5d6f874e947bdaf1a4ffd1"),
   "id":NumberLong(9946),
   "agent":{  
      "id":428,
      "name":"Karan Chandel"
   },
   "all_agents":[  
      428
   ],
   "all_statuses":[  
      1,
      6,
      7
   ],
   "apartment_types":[  
      {  
         "name":"2 BHK",
         "id":3
      }
   ],
   "assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id":244,
   "city_id":37,
   "claimed_at":   ISODate("2018-01-10T11:45:51.460   Z"),
   "country":{  
      "operational":true,
      "url_name":"in",
      "id":49,
      "country_code":"+91",
      "name":"India"
   },
   "created_at":   ISODate("2018-01-08T18:32:11.386   Z"),
   "current_status":{  
      "display_name":"Interested",
      "id":NumberLong(7),
      "name":"Interested"
   },
   "locality_id":533,
   "max_budget":7100000,
   "name":"Nitish Gupta",
   "rating":1,
   "status_timestamps":{  
      "claimed_timestamp": ISODate("2018-01-10T11:45:51.459Z"),
      "interested_timestamp": ISODate("2018-01-10T12:21:48.120Z"),
      "new_timestamp": ISODate("2018-01-08T18:32:11.386Z")
   },
   "status_updated_at":ISODate("2018-01-10T12:21:48.120Z"),
   "tags":{  
      "agent_deactivated":true,
      "is_broker":false,
      "is_duplicate":false,
      "is_incoming_lead":false,
      "is_patch_out_lead":false,
      "is_referral":false
   },
   "calls":[  
      {  
         "second_leg_status":"completed",
         "call_from_agent":true,
         "first_leg_status":"completed",
         "start_time": ISODate("2018-01-10T17:47:20Z"),
         "duration_in_sec":123,
         "agent":{  
            "id":428,
            "name":"Karan Chandel"
         },
         "mapping_id":"244",
         "end_user":{  
            "id":353
         },
         "end_time": ISODate("2018-01-10T17:49:23Z"),
         "id":211,
         "stage":2
      }
   ],
   "event_min_timestamp":   ISODate("2018-01-11T16:46:00Z"),
   "current_inquiry":{  
      "channel_sub_source":null,
      "channel_id":NumberLong(5),
      "channel_source_id":null,
      "channel_name":"magicbricks",
      "placement":"null",
      "channel_sub_source_id":null,
      "channel_source":null,
      "inquiry_id":NumberLong(973246)
   },
   "lead_origin":"digital",
   "location_info":{  
      "location_name":"Balewadi",
      "place_id":"ChIJnQkoQTa5wjsRX5YpGZAuiUM",
      "place_name":"Balewadi,Pune"
   },
   "historical_owners":[  
      {  
         "id":428,
         "name":"Karan Chandel"
      }
   ],
   "assignment_supply_entity_mapping_name":"Pristine Equilife"
}
```

The sample output is as follows.

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "channel_sub_source_id" : NumberLong(128),
                "channel_source_id" : NumberLong(54),
                "channel_id" : NumberLong(116)
        },
        "visits_so_far" : 0,
        "junk" : 5,
        "interested_so_far" : 0,
        "in_visit_done" : 0,
        "in_claimed" : 3,
        "ignored" : 0,
        "failed" : 0,
        "channel_source_id_name" : "btl",
        "bookings" : 0
}
```

Like wise there will be multiple outputs for each combination of _id.

Comment: That's a big agg so it's hard to infer the input and output shapes.   Could you post 1 of the input shapes and also what you want the target output to look like?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Please check, i have made the necessary edits.

Comment: Can you also tell approx how many unique 
                "channel_sub_source_id" : NumberLong(128),
                "channel_source_id" : NumberLong(54),
                "channel_id" : NumberLong(116)
you expect?   Is it like 10 or 10,000?

Comment: The combination can maximum be around 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your data on my MacBook Pro (16G, good proc).  With 1mm records, it took 10.2 seconds.   OK, so in your ballpark.  I stripped it down to just

```
{$group: {_id:null, n: {$sum:1}}
```

and that ran in 380 ms.  With your 3 part group (which with my non-varied data still yields a single group output), that jumped to 2746 millis.   But I think the "culprit" here is the `$addFields`.   When I add a single field in the pipeline before the `$group`, e.g.

```
{"$addFields": { "year":{"$year":"$created_at" }
```

it jumps to ~4300 ms.   If I add just the date fields

```
{"$addFields": { "year":{"$year":"$created_at" }
                 ,"week":{"$week":"$created_at"}
                 ,"month":{"$month":"$created_at"}
                 ,"day":{"$dayOfYear":"$created_at"}
```

It goes to 7100 ms.  So clearly, adding extra info in a pipeline full of docs needs to be done with care.   I notice you are not using most of the added fields; do you need them at all?

Comment: All these add fields are used in the pipeline. We have written a generic generator that generates pipeline. So the fields added via addFields are used in some way by some pipeline.. Not every pipeline uses this. I also noticed this that if i remove addFields the query becomes a bit faster. We cannot completely get away with addFields but we can do something to remove in few cases. Is there any workaround?